# Excel VBA, getting range from an inactive sheet

Tags: excel, vba

This script works fine when I'm viewing the "Temp" sheet. But when I'm in another sheet then the copy command fails. It gives an `Application-defined or object-defined error`:

```
Sheets("Temp").Range(Cells(1), Cells(1).End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("Overview").Range("C40").PasteSpecial
```

I can use this script instead, but then I have problems with pasting it:

```
Sheets("Temp").Columns(1).Copy
Sheets("Overview").Range("C40").PasteSpecial
```

I don't want to activate the "Temp" sheet to get this.

What else can I do?

Comment: I found a solution wich works: Sheets("Temp").Range("A1:A1000").Copy , but I don't like it. I don't want a script with limitations.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your issue is that the because the `Cell` references inside the `Range` 's are unqualified, they refer to a default sheet, which may not be the sheet you intend. 
 For standard modules, the `ThisWorkbook` module, custom classes and user form modules, the defeault is the `ActiveSheet`.  For `Worksheet` code behind modules, it's that worksheet.

For modules other than worksheet code behind modules, your code is actually saying

```
Sheets("Temp").Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1), ActiveSheet.Cells(1).End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("Overview").Range("C40").PasteSpecial
```

For worksheet code behind modules, your code is actually saying

```
Sheets("Temp").Range(Me.Cells(1), Me.Cells(1).End(xlDown)).Copy
Sheets("Overview").Range("C40").PasteSpecial
```

In either case, the solution is the same: fully qualify the range references with the required workbook:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")

With sh1
    .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1,1).End(xlDown)).Copy
End With
sh2.Range("C40").PasteSpecial
```

**Note:** When using `.End(xlDown)` there is a danger that this will result in a range extending further than you expect.  It's better to use `.End(xlUp)` if your sheet layout allows.  If not, check the referenced cell and the cell below for `Empty` first.

Comment: Of Course! You are amazing! :D Thanks a lot. I should use Sheets("Temp").Range(Sheets("Temp").Cells(1), Sheets("Temp").Cells(1).End(xlDown)).Copy . But your version is compact and better formed so I catched it. :)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a problem like this myself: I was trying to search through a separate worksheet to see if the color of a cell matched the color of a cell in a list and return a string value: if you are using .Cells(row, column), you only need this:
Sheets("sheetname").Cells(row, column)
to reference that range of cells.

I was looping through a block of 500 cells and it works surprisingly quickly for me.

I have not tried this with .Copy, but I would assume it would work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

This will do, I don't like to use (xlDown) in case a cell is empty.

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheets("Temp").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Temp")
     .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Copy Sheets("Overview").Range("C40")
End With
```

Or if you want to just use Columns...

```
Sheets("Temp").Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Overview").Range("C40")
```