# Excel VBA negative IF condition

Tags: vba, excel

We have a company macro that cleans data up for us - formatting and arranging data, but as time has gone by our data sets have shifted. Thus, the macro now gives 'false positives' as it were that I want to exclude, but am not sure how.  Reading around the forms, I thought that If Else might work, but I can't seem to get it to work and I wonder if part of it is because things are so similar.

Macro has a roughly 15 lines in a similar fashion to those below

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "RES") Then Cells(i, sitecol) = "Resolution"
If InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "FBK") Then Cells(i, sitecol) = "Facebook"
If InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "ATH") Then Cells(i, sitecol) = "Authority"
```

The problem is the last one, where words including "ATH" are being picked out and changed to 'Authority' in the clean data set when they shouldn't be. How can I tell the macro to ignore anything in placementcol that starts with "EATH" or other combinations I want to exclude?

Comment: Are they all supposed to **start** with the substring? Do you need to check for substring(s) or are you really comparing the entire cell's value?

Comment: I'm really comparing the entire cell values. "Res" or "Ath" can appear anywhere. Plus, this works and I don't want to risk breaking the macro >.<

Comment: Since you already have the one `If` you could nest a second `If` something like `If NOT InStr(1,Cells(i,placementcol), "EATH") AND NOT InStr(1,Cells(i,placementcol), "SATH") then` This isn't tested but might give you what you want with some simple modification .

Comment: As a side note: If you put `@` in front of a users name (@Mike for me) in a comment it will send a notification to that user so they will know that you have responded to something that was posted. You can only do that with one user per comment, though.

Comment: '*I'm really comparing the entire cell values. "Res" or "Ath" can appear anywhere.*' Maybe it is just me but these two sentences completely contradict each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional conditions to your `If` statement.  You can use something of the form

> `If` condition you want
>
> `And` `Not` condition you don't want
>
> `And` `Not` some other condition you don't want ...
>
> `Then` whatever you want to do.

For example:

```
If InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "ATH") _
  And InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "EATH")<>1 Then 
    Cells(i, sitecol) = "Authority"
End If
```

(with `_` to break the statement across multiple lines).

In this case, `InStr(...)<>1` is the same as `Not (InStr(...)=1)` but is shorter to write :) .

**Edit** Expanding on @Jeeped's question, `InStr(1,...)` starts searching at the first character, but may match anywhere.  E.g., `InStr(1,"foo","o")=2`.

- If you are searching anywhere in the string, you can remove the `1,`.
- If you are looking only for cell values that *start with* the given text, replace

  ```
   If InStr(1, Cells(), "")
  ```

  with

  ```
   If InStr(Cells(), "")=1
  ```

**By the way,** to avoid problems down the road, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048359/2877364) regarding using `With` ... `.Cells()` rather than an unqualified `Cells`.

**Edit 2**

Based on your comment, I think you are looking anywhere in the string, not just at the start of the string.  Then try something like this, for a single condition:

```
Dim celltext As String
celltext = CStr(Cells(i, placementcol).Value)
If ( InStr(celltext, "ATH") >= 1 ) _
  And ( InStr(celltext, "EATH") = 0 ) Then 
    Cells(i, sitecol) = "Authority"
End If
```

(For the other `If` statements, you can reuse `celltext` — you don't have to repeat the `Dim` and `celltext=...` lines each time.)

This does four things differently:

1. Uses parentheses around each test to make sure there are no misinterpretations;
2. Expressly checks `ATH` with `>= 1`, i.e., somewhere in the string;
3. Expressly checks `EATH` with `= 0`, i.e., nowhere in the string; and
4. Uses `celltext` to make sure that you actually have the real text result from `Cells(i, placementcol)` and not a `Null` or some other value.

I also took out the leading `1,`s.

Comment: What her block of condition statements needs is to be converted to a Select Case black or factor in ElseIf so that if the first condition is met, 14 more are not evaluated.

Comment: I wanted so badly for this to work. Sadly, it doesn't, regardless of whether or not I remove the '1' to indicate where to search or if I use `Instr(...)<>1` or `Not Instr(...)=1`.  Are there other options, or could something else where in the Macro be affecting this?

Comment: @Jeeped post an answer and I'll upvote it :) .  I thought about the `ElseIf` as well but didn't think I had enough context to write a broader answer.

Comment: @Jenny Try the "Edit 2" code and see what happens.  Yes, it could always be something elsewhere in the macro :) .  It could also be something screwy in your data.

Comment: Played around with it and what worked was `If InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "ATH") And InStr(1, Cells(i, placementcol), "EATH") = 0 Then Cells(i, sitecol) = "Authority"`.  Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to "[`Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/gg251796.aspx)" VBA :

```
If Cells(i, placementcol) Like "*[A-DF-Z]ATH*" Then Cells(i, sitecol) = "Authority"
```

`*` matches any 0 or more characters and `[A-DF-Z]` matches any letter except E, so it won't match strings that contain EATH (unless they contain more than one ATH)

---

Also, [`ElseIf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx) can be used to ignore the rest of the checks:

```
 If Cells(i, placementcol) Like "*FBK*" Then
     Cells(i, sitecol) = "Facebook"
 ElseIf Cells(i, placementcol) Like "*EATH*" Then
     ' ignore
 ElseIf Cells(i, placementcol) Like "*ATH*" And Then
     Cells(i, sitecol) = "Authority"
 End If
```