# VBA: Sum of values in a range to Label.caption is always 0

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I might be not understanding something here. I try to look for the last row in a datasheet and sum up a range. But for some reason it spits out 0, for both values (there are numbers in the cells.).

```
 lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

Offene_PZ_Form.AZ_Lager.Caption = Application.Sum(Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(3, 19), Cells(lRow, 19)))
Offene_PZ_Form.AZ_Fehlt.Caption = Application.Sum(Worksheets("Data").Range(Cells(3, 20), Cells(lRow, 20)))
```

Comment: `Range(Cells, Cells)` is problematic... see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet).

Comment: do you have `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: @ScottCraner No, I don't...

Comment: Do the cells contain *text-that-looks-like-numbers*? What is the result if you just manually `=SUM()` that range?

Comment: Well. So the cells (i call it cell1) are referencing to another cell (cell2), which contents are formatted as text (cell 2 comes from a textbox), and cell1 has an if clause in it (`=IF(A10=FALSE;J10;0)`. So cell 2 will be a text as well? (Excel doesnt mark it as text tho) (Sum is 0)

Comment: Yes it will be text... You can force it to be a number with `--`

Comment: if `J10` is text then the formula will return text.

Comment: where do I need to - - ?

Comment: `=IF(A10=FALSE;--J10;0)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that works, getting smarter every question i ask on here lol! SO's member are (almost everytime) so helpful. thank you guys

Comment: You could also do `=NOT(A10)*J10` If it is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: The true/false statement comes from a checkbox, so that would be possible too.
I added `PZE_RNG.Offset(0, 17) = "=IF(RC[-18]=FALSE,RC[-9],0)"` to some line of code I need (to put in the formula relative to the cell "PZE_RNG"). would this be converted to `PZE_RNG.Offset(0, 17) = "=IF(RC[-18]=FALSE,--RC[-9],0)"`?