# Updating source data range for a chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I have some data tabulated onto worksheet("MAIN") columns Y:AB.  The data were to be plotted as a chart.  I would like to make the start and the end of data dynamically change with the start of row (Range("E8"), calculated) and the end of the row (Range("E9"), calculated).

I have the code:

```
Sub chRNG()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MAIN")

Dim st As Long, ed As Long
st = ws.Range("E8").Value       'start of data row, obtained from worksheet formula
ed = ws.Range("E9").Value       'end of data row, obtained from worksheet formula

Dim Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5 as long
Field1 = ws.Range("A:AZ").find("criteria_1").column
'
'
'
Field5 = ws.Range("A:AZ").find("criteria_5").column

Dim chRng As Range
Set chRng = ws.Range(Cells(st, Field1), Cells(ed, Field5))

With ws
.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData _
    Source:=.Range("chRng"), _
    PlotBy:=xlColumns
End With

End Sub
```

Every-time I run this procedures, only the end of data was updated, but not the start of data.  When I right-click on the chart, choose "select data" and examine the data source, the source became =MAIN!$X$1:$AB$4401 let's say.

Why the start wasn't updated?

Comment: Probably a side note, but see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet): `Set chRng = ws.Range(Cells(st, Field1), Cells(ed, Field5))` is problematic.

Comment: `Source:=.Range("chRng")` - should be `Source:=chRng` probably.

Comment: Did something similar a long time ago, but the chart referenced a fixed set of cells and the data in those cells was updated as needed.

Comment: @BigBen thank you.  You're right with the syntax.  My chart, however, have date series also.  My code cannot update the date range.  Any ideas?