# VBA Extract Unique Values with Advance Filter From One Worksheet to Another

Tags: excel, vba, unique-values, advanced-filter

So I have this Workbook contains several worksheets.

In Sheet22 is a database and I need to extract unique values from one of its columns, which is Column "BC" (or Col 55).
here is to illustrate the unique values that I want to extract:

[image: column that I want to extract unique values]

 I need to extract the unique values to another worksheet (Sheet 32) starts from Range A1. But before that, I need to clear the target range first if it is not empty, then after that, paste the unique values.

so this is the codes I used, (fyi I'm, still new to VBA, so I found this code to be the closest to what I have in mind and modified it):

```
Option Explicit

Sub uniqueValuesFromRangeCustomer()

    Dim rngCollectFrom As Range, targetRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet22")

    'Set the target range where the unique values will be copied to
    Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet32").Range("A1")

    'Clear the target range if it is not empty
    If targetRange <> vbNullString Then
        'Find last row in target range column
        lastRow = Sheets("Sheet32").Columns(targetRange.Column).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        'Delete target range
        Sheets("Sheet32").Range(targetRange, Cells(lastRow, targetRange.Column)).Delete xlUp
        'Reset target range (since it gets deleted)
        Set targetRange = Sheets("Sheet32").Range("A1")
    End If

    'Define the range the unique values will be extracted from
    'Find last row
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet22").Columns(55).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    'Set the source range
    Set rngCollectFrom = Sheets("Sheet22").Range(Cells(2, 55), Cells(lastRow, 55))

    'Use Advanced Filter
    rngCollectFrom.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=targetRange, unique:=True
```

When I run the code, I got error message: "Subscript out of range", and when I debug, it highlights the code:

```
Set sh: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet22")
```

I still don't understand how to modify this code to works, please someone if can help me with this problem.
Thanks before!

Comment: That means the workbook that contains the code does not have a sheet named "Sheet22"

Comment: @BigBen I was using code name instead of the worksheet name. The worksheet name is "Database", and the code name is "Sheet22", so there is a "Sheet22" in that workbook.

Comment: You need to use the worksheet name. So, either `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")`, or just `Sheet22`.

Comment: @BigBen OK, so I have changed them all to worksheet name. `Sheets("Sheet22")` become `Sheets("Database")`  and also `Sheets("Sheet32")`  become `Sheets("Summary")` , and that solves the error. But now, another error saying "Application-defined or object-defined error" and it highlights the code `Set rngCollectFrom = Sheets("Database").Range(Cells(2, 55), Cells(lastRow, 55))`.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: [Qualify the worksheet the `Cells` are on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet).

Comment: @BigBen I have added `Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Database")` and `Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")`. And qualify the worksheets to `Set rngCollectFrom = sh1.Range(Cells(2, 55), Cells(lastRow, 55))`. But still error, it gives "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed". on that line of code. How to qualify this code the right way?

Comment: `sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(2, 55), sh1.Cells(lastRow, 55))`.