# Id like to reference a range in another workbook but get error 13 (VBA says its not a range)

Tags: excel, vba

When I run this I get a run time error (13) telling me after setting (what I think is a) range in those workbooks that it is, in fact, is not a range. I think there's a problem in my nomenclature, but can you guys help me out? Thanks

```
Option Explicit
Dim OGBook As Workbook
Dim NAVBook As Workbook
Sub NAVCheck()

Dim NetAmountColumn As Range
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim SingleCell As Range
Dim CodeColumn As Range

Set NAVBook = FindWorkbook(sWithNameLike:="This_function_isnt_the_problem")
Set OGBook = Workbooks("some_file.xlsm")
Set NetAmountColumn = Workbooks(OGBook).Range("i2", Range("i1").End(xlDown))
Set TargetRange = Workbooks(OGBook).Range("o2", Range("o1").End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1)
Set CodeColumn = Workbooks(NAVBook).Range("c2", Range("c1").End(xlDown))


If NAVBook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("NAV Workbook doesn't seem to be open. Please open current NAV workbook and run the program again.")
    
Else
    
    [Something I haven't written yet]
 
End If


End Sub
```

Sorry for the sloppy indentation.

Comment: A `Workbook` does not have a `Range` property, btw.

Comment: `Set NetAmountColumn = OGBook.Worksheets("Yourworksheetnamehere").Range(...)`

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet) for how to reference a range on an inactive sheet properly.