# Search List form only working if correct tab open

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating my first vba user form and im trying to populate a listbox with data, i have it working however if the correct tab isn't open then the data is not added to the list box.

```
Option Explicit


' Display All Matches from Search in Userform ListBox
'
Dim FormEvents As Boolean

Private Sub ClearForm(Except As String)

' Clears the list box and text boxes EXCEPT the text box
' currently having data entered into it

    Select Case Except
    
        Case "txtType"
            FormEvents = False
            txtStoresCode.Value = ""
            txtDesc.Value = ""
            txtEquipment.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True

        Case "txtStoresCode"
            FormEvents = False
            txtType.Value = ""
            txtDesc.Value = ""
            txtEquipment.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True

        Case "txtDesc"
            FormEvents = False
            txtType.Value = ""
            txtStoresCode.Value = ""
            txtEquipment.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True

        Case "txtEquipment"
            FormEvents = False
            txtType.Value = ""
            txtStoresCode.Value = ""
            txtDesc.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True
        
        Case Else
            FormEvents = False
            txtType.Value = ""
            txtStoresCode.Value = ""
            txtDesc.Value = ""
            txtEquipment.Value = ""
            Results.Clear
            FormEvents = True
            
        End Select

End Sub

Private Sub ClearBtn_Click()

    ClearForm ("")
    
End Sub

Private Sub CloseBtn_Click()
    
    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub txtType_Change()
    
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("txtType")
    
End Sub


Private Sub txtStoresCode_Change()
    
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("txtStoresCode")
    
End Sub

Private Sub txtDesc_Change()
    
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("txtDesc")
    
End Sub

Private Sub txtEquipment_Change()
    
    If FormEvents Then ClearForm ("txtEquipment")
    
End Sub

Private Sub SearchBtn_Click()

    Dim SearchTerm As String
    Dim SearchColumn As String
    Dim RecordRange As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim FirstCell As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    
       
   
    ' Display an error if no search term is entered
    If txtType.Value = "" And txtStoresCode.Value = "" And txtDesc.Value = "" And txtEquipment.Value = "" Then
    
        MsgBox "No search term specified", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    
    End If
    
    ' Work out what is being searched for
    If txtType.Value <> "" Then
    
        SearchTerm = txtType.Value
        SearchColumn = "Type"
        
    End If
    
    If txtStoresCode.Value <> "" Then
    
        SearchTerm = txtStoresCode.Value
        SearchColumn = "StoresCode"
        
    End If

    If txtDesc.Value <> "" Then
    
        SearchTerm = txtDesc.Value
        SearchColumn = "Description"
        
    End If

    If txtEquipment.Value <> "" Then
    
        SearchTerm = txtEquipment.Value
        SearchColumn = "Equipment"
        
    End If
    
    Results.Clear
    
        ' Only search in the relevant table column i.e. if somone is searching Location
        ' only search in the Location column
        With Range("Table1[" & SearchColumn & "]")
            ' Find the first match
            Set RecordRange = .Find(SearchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues)

            ' If a match has been found
            If Not RecordRange Is Nothing Then

                FirstAddress = RecordRange.Address
                RowCount = 0

                Do
                
                    ' Set the first cell in the row of the matching value
                    Set FirstCell = Range("A" & RecordRange.Row)
                    
                    Results.AddItem
                    Results.List(RowCount, 0) = FirstCell(1, 1).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 1) = FirstCell(1, 3).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 2) = FirstCell(1, 4).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 3) = FirstCell(1, 5).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 4) = FirstCell(1, 6).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 5) = FirstCell(1, 7).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 6) = FirstCell(1, 8).Value
                    Results.List(RowCount, 7) = FirstCell(1, 9).Value
                    RowCount = RowCount + 1
                    
                    ' Look for next match
                    Set RecordRange = .FindNext(RecordRange)

                    ' When no further matches are found, exit the sub
                    If RecordRange Is Nothing Then

                        Exit Sub

                    End If

                ' Keep looking while unique matches are found
                Loop While RecordRange.Address <> FirstAddress

            Else
            
                ' If you get here, no matches were found
                Results.AddItem
                Results.List(RowCount, 0) = "Nothing Found"
            
            End If

        End With

End Sub





Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    FormEvents = True
```

I've tied everything that i am able to find online.

I'm hoping that someone will be able to point me in the correct direction.

Comment: This line: `Set FirstCell = Range("A" & RecordRange.Row)` will always use the `ActiveSheet` and that is probably not your intent. Qualify that range with the sheet it's from.

Comment: oh thats great, but could you suggest the best was to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet

Comment: i really appreciate that but still cant out my finger on the correct way to qualify that range everything i try just doesn't seen to work. any chance youd be able to show me how in this case?