# Save As an Excel file with a file name that includes yesterday's date and data from a cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that saves an Excel file with file name that includes the previous day date.
It works fine, but I also want to include in the file name a text that exists in another sheet (sheet name is DSP) and in cell <kbd>B8</kbd>

This is the code I have:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "\\mypath\" & _
    "Azal PHR " & Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: & Worksheets("DSP").Range("B8").Value

Comment: I have found my mistake. the sheet is in another file called PHR Automatic in the same path, so How to include it now?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet

Answer (score 0):

Just need to concatenate the workbook and sheet reference to the end. Note you may need to change the workbook name depending on the file extension (e.g. if it has macros as well it will be .xlsm)

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "\\mypath\" & "Azal PHR " & _ 
Format(Date - 1, "mm-dd-yyyy") & _ 
Excel.Workbooks("PHR Automatic.xlsx").Worksheets("DSP").Range("B8").Value
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working

Comment: @hussam What is the output?