# .Range(.Cells ... vs .Range( Cells... vs "Microsoft Learn" page

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell, offset

Surely the essence of my Question has come up before. What may be new about my Question is that it refers to what I hope is an error [on this Microsoft.Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells#example), and possibly my inane/deep questions. (Questions aren't deep, Answers might be.)

Actually, I've spent so much time on the code below that I'm ***sure*** the example linked to above is incorrect. Just an "ever-so-slight" oops. (Dot? No dot?)

But I'm not exactly sure why it's wrong and/or how how to interpret the "dot-versus-no-dot" appearance of `.Range(Cells` and `.Range(.Cells` in their contexts.

Specifically, what do the dots in `.Cells` actually do or refer to? If the answer is simply, "they cause offsets", okay, but other than executing the code and seeing that is the effect, how does this happen?

And what does the absence of dots before `Cells` do? Again, "the result is relative references" isn't what I'm after. But maybe those two answers are just how it is, so move on.

Maybe I haven't grasped the nuances of `.Range(Cells` vs. `.Range(.Cells`. Or maybe it's just `Cells` vs `.Cells`.

Exactly what does `.Cells` have to do with the `With` and Range("B2:Z100)?

I added to the example and included notes that I hope make sense: (Refer to P.S.)

```
    Sub cat()
      
          With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E20")
'   Microsoft's code ...                                           
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 3)).Font.Bold = True
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 3)).Select
            MsgBox Selection.Address '             affects C3:E7 (not B2:D6)
    
'  My code ...     
            .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 3)).Font.Color = vbRed
            .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 3)).Select
            MsgBox Selection.Address '                      DOES affect B2:D6
            
          End With
        End Sub
```

**P.S.** I just looked at the last two examples in the link I provided. I think it might help me a lot to trace execution on paper of those two hunks of code and see if I can get the same outputs. It's not "simply" a `Cells` vs. `.Cells` deal, but a pretty deep dive into all of the above, plus an interesting experience with `Item`, which I thought I knew the meaning and usage of, but am now not sure, in the context provided.

*Explanation* (not required reading(!), but looking for improvements)

Beneath the `With` ...

`.Range(.Cells` does NOT involve relative references because of the dots before `Cells`.

Instead the arguments of Cells look like OFFSETs from B2. If they are...

`.Range(.Cells(1,1))` says apply `Offset(1,1)` to B2, which gives C3 and

`.Range(.Cells(5,3))` says apply `Offset(5,3)` to B2, which gives E7.

So Cells C3:E7 will be **bold**.

Further down ...

second `.Range(Cells` DOES contain RELATIVE REFERENCE to B2.

So `Cells(1,1)` represents 1st row and 1st col relative to B2, which is B2.

and `Cells(5,3)` represents 5th row and 3rd col relative to B2, which is D6.

So B2:D6 will be *red*.

Comment: For the meaning of the `.`'s, [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048359/445425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The example is wrong. But your conclusion (offset) also is not correct.

The culprit is [Range.Range property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range) where at least property `Cell1` is "The **name** of the range." and not a `Cell` object. And, if not named, the name of a cell is it's address.

The problem is that the cell address got from a cell object will always be related to the sheet. However, when used in Range.Range, it is interpreted in relation to the parent range. Thus `Range.Range("A1:A1")` is the range of cell in first row, first column in parent range. And `Range.Range("C3:C3")` is the range of cell in third row, third column in parent range.

Following example should show the problem:

```
Sub test()

 With ActiveSheet.Range("C3:Z100")
  Set o = .Cells(1, 1)
  MsgBox o.Address '$C$3
  Set o = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1)) 'is .Range("C3:C3") - third row, third column in parent range
  MsgBox o.Address '$E$5
  
  Set o = Cells(1, 1) 'is Activesheet.Cells(1, 1)
  MsgBox o.Address '$A$1
  Set o = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)) 'is .Range("A1:A1") - first row, first column in parent range
  MsgBox o.Address '$C$3
  
 End With
End Sub
```

This shall show the problem. It is not the solution. The above only works when all is in `ActiveSheet`. Following will fail:

```
Sub test2()
 Set oWs = Worksheets("Data") ' Worksheet named "Data" is not the ActiveSheet
 With oWs.Range("C3:Z100")
  Set o = .Cells(1, 1)
  MsgBox o.Address(External:=True) '[WBName]Data!$C$3
  Set o = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1)) 'is .Range("[WBName]Data!C3:C3") - third row, third column in parent range
  MsgBox o.Address(External:=True) '[WBName]Data!$E$5
  
  Set o = Cells(1, 1) 'is Activesheet.Cells(1, 1)
  MsgBox o.Address(External:=True) '[WBName]NameOfActiveSheet!$A$1
  Set o = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)) 'is .Range("NameOfActiveSheet!A1:A1") - Error 1004!
    
 End With
End Sub
```

The error is thrown because the range named `NameOfActiveSheet!A1:A1` cannot be found in parent range `Data!C3:Z100`.

So correct usage not using `ActiveSheet` will be:

```
Sub test3()

 Set oWs = Worksheets("Data") ' Worksheet named "Data" is not the ActiveSheet
 With oWs.Range("C3:Z100")
  Set o = .Range(oWs.Cells(1, 1), oWs.Cells(1, 1)) 'is .Range("[WBName]Data!A1:A1") - first row, first column in parent range
  MsgBox o.Address(External:=True) '[WBName]Data!$C$3
  
  Set o = .Range(oWs.Cells(1, 1), oWs.Cells(5, 3))
  MsgBox o.Address(External:=True) '[WBName]Data!$C$3:$E$7
  o.Interior.Color = vbRed
  
 End With
End Sub
```

I know this is not really straight forward. And it looks to me like a kind of bug in Microsoft Excel VBA. But it only affects `Range.Range`, which gets a sub range out of a given range. Simplest solution would be to avoid this and always using `Worksheet.Range`.

Comment: I was creating an answer (until I noticed it wasn't really what OP was asking about) and stumbled upon the error when using a worksheet object like `With ws.Range("C3:Z100")` with `Set ws = Worksheets("Data")` (not the ActiveSheet). Your last `Set o` would throw an error in this With, why's that? Or is that an issue with `Cells(1,1)` referring to the ActiveSheet then and that giving an issue because it's not part of the Parent on the other sheet? I thought it'd see it as "A1:A1" first row, first column of `ws.Range("C3:Z100")` like with the rest.

Comment: @Notus_Panda:  See addition in my answer.

Comment: Ah thanks, that confirms my assumption. In my testing, I was more looking at the values instead of the full addresses so this visualization helped. I don't usually go `.Range().Range()` but it's good to keep in mind if it does occur (and to keep learning).