# Loop through worksheets (and apply conditional formatting)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

This sub doesn't loop through the worksheets properly, what am I missing?

I know the formatting rules can be made better but it has to be like this so the user can copy/paste his own rules quickly into the code (macro recorder -> create a new conditional formatting rule in a specific way (!) -> stop macro. Then the macro spits out the code for ALL conditional formatting rules!).

The looping doesn't work. I don't get any error message.

```
Sub Test()

Dim rg As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook


i = wb.Worksheets.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
'COPY CODE BETWEEN "OBERES ENDE" and "UNTERES ENDE"


 For j = 6 To i  
 wb.Sheets(j).Activate
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------- OBERES ENDE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

' only one as example

    Columns("A:K").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$K1=50%"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        
    
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------- UNTERES ENDE --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Next j

wb.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "what am I missing?" `wb.Sheets(j).Activate` after `For j = 6 To i `

Comment: Why do I have to activate the sheet here? usualy. Activate isn't really used iirc. Do you have some further reading?

Comment: Does it work if you add that line ?

Comment: It does, I was testing it just until now! Do you have any info regarding my question above in this comment line?

Comment: Without a worksheet reference `Columns("A:K")` is the default/active sheet. Looping through j is not changing that. It's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047943/excel-vba-getting-range-from-an-inactive-sheet)

Comment: What you want is effectively `wb.Sheets(j).Columns("A:K").Select` but to do that you need to activate the sheet first .

Answer (score 2):

No need for `Selection`, use `With`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook, j As Integer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = 6 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        With wb.Sheets(j).Columns("A:K")
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$K1=50%"
            .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
             With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(255, 192, 0) ' 49407
                .TintAndShade = 0
             End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wb.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Selection is necessary in my case, I even explained why! Please read the question more carefully.